# Send/Receive text with buffer using sockets in Delphi

Tags: sockets, delphi, text, buffer, delphi-7

So I have searched for a way to make this work but found no working solution. I am trying to send text that has been inserted in to a memo from the Client to the Server using sockets. Unfortunately I cannot get the coding working. It might be something stupid I'm doing wrong; but I don't know where the mistake is. I created a stable connection between the server and client, and I am able to send text using `Server.Socket.Connections[Form1.ListView1.Selected.Index].SendText('Texthere');` but I just cant get it to send and receive text or anything using buffers.

Code on Client:

```pascal
procedure TIBAT.Sends1Click(Sender: TObject); //Button to start the sending of the text on the memo component
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  size: Integer;
begin
  if (Form1.ListView1.Selected <> nil) then //if a server is selected
  begin
  Form1.Server.Socket.Connections[Form1.ListView1.Selected.Index].SendText('IBAT');
    ms:= TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      IBAT.Memo1.Lines.SaveToStream(ms);
      ms.Position:= 0;
      Size:= MS.Size;    
     Form1.Server.Socket.Connections[Form1.ListView1.Selected.Index].SendBuf(Size,SizeOf(Size));
     Form1.Server.Socket.Connections[Form1.ListView1.Selected.Index].SendStream(ms);
    except
      ms.Free;
      ShowMessage('FAILED');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Code on the Server:

```pascal
private
    Stream: TMemoryStream;
    FSize: Integer;
    writing: Boolean;

...

procedure TSock.ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Command     :String;
  BytesReceived: Longint;
  CopyBuffer: Pointer; //buffer for copying
  ChunkSize: Integer;
  TempSize: Integer;
const
  MaxChunkSize: Longint = 8192;
begin
  Command := Socket.ReceiveText;
if split(Command, '|', 0) = 'IBAT' then
  begin
  If FSize=0 then
      begin
        //ShowMessage(IntToStr(Socket.ReceiveLength)); added messageboxes everywhere to figure out where the problem is
        If Socket.ReceiveLength>SizeOf(TempSize) then
        begin
          Socket.ReceiveBuf(TempSize,SizeOf(TempSize));
          Stream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
          Stream.SetSize(TempSize);
          //ShowMessage(IntToStr(TempSize));
          FSize:= TempSize;
          writing:= True;
        End;
      End;
      If (FSize>0) and (writing) then
      begin
        GetMem(CopyBuffer, MaxChunkSize); //allocate the buffer
        While Socket.ReceiveLength>0 do
        Begin
          ChunkSize:= Socket.ReceiveLength;
          If ChunkSize > MaxChunkSize then ChunkSize:= MaxChunkSize;
          BytesReceived:= Socket.ReceiveBuf(CopyBuffer^,ChunkSize);
          Stream.Write(CopyBuffer^, BytesReceived); //write chunk
          Dec(FSize,BytesReceived);
        End;
        FreeMem(CopyBuffer, MaxChunkSize); //free allocated buffer
        If FSize = 0 then
        begin
        Stream.SaveToFile(TempDir+IntToStr(GetTickCount)+'.cmd');
        Socket.SendText('File received!');
        Stream.SetSize(0);
        FSize:= 0;
        End;
    FreeMem(CopyBuffer, MaxChunkSize);
    Writing:= False;
    End;
end;
```

I know using Indy is more effective and better than sockets, but I've already started coding using it and switching over to Indy is a big pain. 
If anyone can help me get this working I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I can't understand how you think this is easier than Indy.

Comment: It probably isn't but I have no experience with IdTCP components. If I cannot get an answer for this question above I guess I will be forced to learn how to use Indy instead of Sockets.

Comment: You will continue to find situations where your code needs to be extended and tweaked. It will pay off tenfold to find out how Indy components work. It is not difficult, just find an example to start with.

Comment: Well looks like im switching over to Indy. I really hope its worth the work. I will be posting here if I get stuck again hahaha. stackoverflow probably hasn't seen the last of me.

Comment: It seems you have completely ignored all of the code I gave you in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102283/). You are still not taking into account that `Send...()` and `Receive...()` can send/read partial data that must be buffered, or that received data can span across multiple `OnRead` events and so must be buffered as well. And you are not doing any error handling on the sends/reads. I gave you a complete buffering solution earlier, but I don't see any trace of it in this code. Rewriting your code to send/read a stream does not change the fundamental rules.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did look at your code, and I still could not get it working. But no matter since I followed your advice and went for indy. It does seem easier to do so why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just make a very-very simple example of TCP client and server on Indy. It is very simple, even no exceptions handling there.

Take a look at [a repository at github](https://github.com/vladon/IdTcpClientAndServerExample) and feel free to ask any questions.

Anyway, using of native socket components is not a good idea. Try to study Indy, then Synapse or mORMot may be. Indy will be a good start.

**UPD** I'll try to get some code here in answer:

Start a TCP server listening on specified port:

```
var
  IdTcpServer1: TIdTcpServer

[...]

IdTcpServer1.DefaultPort := SERVER_PORT;
IdTcpServer1.Active := True;
```

Server will start listening on 0.0.0.0:1234.

Connect a TCP client to TCP server:

```
var
  IdTcpClient1: TIdTcpClient;

[...]

IdTcpClient1.Host := SERVER_HOST; // IP or DNS name
IdTcpClient1.Port := SERVER_PORT;
IdTcpClient1.Connect;
```

Send a text line to socket (after it's connected):

```
IdTcpClient1.IOHandler.Writeln('Hello world!');
```

Server must implement `OnExecute` event handler:

```
// manual init in code or you can assign it in design-time in IDE
IdTcpServer1.OnExecute := IdTcpServer1ExecuteHandler;

[...]

// very simple example
procedure IdTcpServer1ExecuteHandler(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  if s <> EmptyStr then
  begin
    // do something with received string s
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there is too much code there, is it necessary to post all of it here?

Comment: Well, personally I'm no fan of an answer like this.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question at all. What will readers do a year from now when your repository no longer exists?

Comment: @TomBrunberg and other guys: I've updated answer and included some sample code in answer